# psql: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, sql

I checked a lot on the Internet to fix the problem but couldn't do anything.

First of all, I changed my configuration based on here.

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port= 5432
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main'
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql,/tmp'    # comma-separated list >
                                        # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_group = ''                  # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_permissions = 0777          # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                                        # (change requires restart)
bonjour = off                           # advertise server via Bonjour
                                        # (change requires restart)
bonjour_name = ''               
ali@ali:~$ sudo systemctl restart postgresql
ali@ali:~$ psql
$ psql
psql: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
ali@ali:~$ export PGHOST=localhost
ali@ali:~$ psql
psql: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

my hba file:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
host   all             postgres                                peer 
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0              md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          md5
```

```
ali@ali:$~ sudo ufw allow 5432
ali@ali:$~ sudo ufw status
WARN: /etc is world writable!
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5433                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5433 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

ali@ali:$~ netstat -lntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46589         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36287         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37915         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40483         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42069           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2628          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::1716                 :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42069           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60941           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::56614                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::1716                 :::*
```

It seems port 5432 is not open, I couldn't open the port anyway :(
I also changed the permissions by chmod to 777
I don't know what should i do.
Ubuntu version 20.04.03
Postgradesql version: 9.3
I had the same problem when I installed postgradesql 14 or 15 or 16 ...

```
    abolfazl@abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK:~$ sudo systemctl status 'postgresql*'
    × postgresql@16-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 16-main
         Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
         Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Fri 2023-12-29 17:32:51 +0330; 10min ago
        Process: 7640 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 16-main start (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
            CPU: 57ms
    
    Dec 29 17:32:51 abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 16-main...
    Dec 29 17:32:51 abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK postgresql@16-main[7640]: Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at >
    Dec 29 17:32:51 abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK systemd[1]: postgresql@16-main.service: Can't open PID file /run/postgresql/16-main.pid (ye>
    Dec 29 17:32:51 abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK systemd[1]: postgresql@16-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
    Dec 29 17:32:51 abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 16-main.
    
    ● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
         Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
         Active: active (exited) since Fri 2023-12-29 17:32:51 +0330; 10min ago
        Process: 7641 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
       Main PID: 7641 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
            CPU: 2ms
    
    Dec 29 17:32:51 abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
    Dec 29 17:32:51 abolfazl-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.
    lines 1-21/21 (END)
```

Comment: Are you sure the server is running? Try `systemctl status postgresql`.

Comment: @jos I edited the question, Check it out.

Comment: It is `active (exited)` whereas it should be `active (running)`. Find out why it exited, in the PostgreSQL logs.

Comment: There is nothing in the logs. I don't know why @Jos

Comment: I updated the Question with the result of this command: sudo systemctl status 'postgresql*'
It will help you to help me better, I think the problem came from the permissions ... @Jos

Comment: I don't know what "permissions" you are refering to. Trying to find an open port while the server isn't running is bound to fail. Try `journalctl -xe` to find what is wrong with the server.